# How to determine if two vectors are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to find if the following two vectors are linearly independent:

> $$v_1 = [0, -10,0]$$
> $$v_2 = [-2, -4, -6]$$

I tried to multiplying $v_1\cdot v_2^T$ so I can get an $n \times n$ matrix and then find its determinant, but it's not working.  Is this possible to do?

Comment: Two vectors are linearly dependent iff $v_1 = c v_2$ for some real constant $c$. In this given example it is clear that for no real constant $c$ would the equality $v_1 = cv_2$ hold. Therefore, these vectors are not linearly dependent.

Comment: @sudeep5221Thank you that makes sense. How would I determine c?  Is it possible to do it algebraically?  c = v1/v2?

Comment: You cannot divide vectors like that. You would have to divide the corresponding elements of the vector to see the proportion (which will be $c$) comes out to be same in all the cases

Comment: Specifically, in the example in your query, looking at the middle component, since $(-4) \times 2.5 = (-10),$ if the vectors are in fact dependent, then $c$ must $= 2.5$.  However, trying that specific value for $c$ fails with either the 1st or 3rd components (in this case it actually fails on both the 1st and 3rd components).  Therefore, no satisfying scalar $c$ can exist.  Therefore, the two vectors can **not** be dependent.  Therefore the two vectors **must** be independent.

Comment: Also, adding to previous comments, $v_1v_2^T$ always has zero determinant (of course, if it is a square matrix). So, it won't help. For more than two vectors, write them as columns (or rows) of a matrix and find it's rank.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors $v_1,v_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independend if $$\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda = \mu = 0$$ for $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$.

In the case of two vectors, that means, that they are linearly independend iff there is no real number that can turn $v_1$ into $v_2$ and vice versa.

An example for two *linearly dependend* vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}$ because

$$2v_1 + (- 1)v_2 = 0$$

In your case, there are no scalars $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{R}$ (other than $\lambda = \mu = 0)$ such that
$$\lambda v_1 + \mu v_2 = 0.$$

Comment: Linearly *dependent*.

Comment: ah, good catch. Thanks Ted. That was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

What I am about to say does not generalize to all dimensions, but since you are dealing with vectors in three dimensions, the cross product is available to you. Compute the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two vectors using the formula in the link. The original two vectors are linearly independent if and only if the result is a non-zero vector. This can be proven using the sine formula for the cross product's magnitude, that is $$\|a\times b\|=\|a\|\cdot\|b\|\cdot |\sin \theta|,$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between the original two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors are linearly dependent if and only if one is a multiple of the other.